# why sizeof operator does not show size to be 20?

Tags: c++

```
    #include "iostream"
    using namespace std;
    class Algebra
    {
    private:
        int a, b;
        const int c;
        const int d;
        static int s;


    public:
        //default constructor
        Algebra() : c(0), d(0)
        {
            s++;
            a = b = 0;
            cout << "Default Constructor" << endl;
        }
        //parameterized (overloaded) constructor
        Algebra(int a, int b, int c1, int d1) : c(c1), d(d1)
        {
            s++;
            setA(a);
            setB(b);
            cout << "Parameterized Constructor" << endl;
        }
        //copy (overloaded) constructor
        Algebra(const Algebra &obj) : c(obj.c), d(obj.d)
        {
            s++;
            this->a = obj.a;
            this->b = obj.b;
            cout << "Copy Constructor" << endl;
        }
        //Destructor
        ~Algebra()
        {
            s--;
            cout << "Destructor Called" << endl;
        }
        //Setter for static member s
        static void setS(int s)
        {
            Algebra::s = s;
        }

        //Getter for static member s
        static int getS()
        {
            return s;
        }

        //Getter for constant data member c
        int getC() const
        {
            return this->c;
        }

        //Setter for data member a
        void setA(int a)
        {
            if(a < 0)
                this->a = 0;
            else
                this->a = a;
        }
        //Setter for data member b
        void setB(int b)
        {
            if(b < 0)
                this->b = 0;
            else
                this->b = b;
        }
    };
    int Algebra::s = 90;
    int main()
    {
        Algebra obj1, obj2(1, 2, 3,4), obj3(obj1);
        cout << "Size of object = " << sizeof(obj1) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

why the sizeof operator show size to be 16,where i have declared 5 data members of int type.it should add up all 5 data members and give the result as 20. i have also checked sizeof operator on static int variable separately which works fine.

Comment: You can think of it as a global object with access restrictions inside a namespace (that of the class).

Comment: @JasonR: Once more, answers to the question belong in the _answer_ section. It's down below.

Comment: 16... on a machine where `sizeof( int ) == 4`. Don't assume that this will be the case everywhere.

Comment: Do you really need **all that code** to show a simple question about `sizeof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static member doesn't contribute to the size of a class instance, as you only need one copy for your entire program, not one per instance. Therefore, the size consists of 4 ints, which is 16 bytes on your platform.